# Invariant holds but postcondition fails or verifier times out

Tags: dafny

I've been trying to prove this, but it doesn't verify:

```
method MoveZeroesToEnd(arr: array<int>)
    requires arr.Length >= 2
    modifies arr
    // Same size
    ensures arr.Length == old(arr.Length)
    // Zeros to the right of the first zero
    ensures forall i, j :: 0 <= i < j < arr.Length && arr[i] == 0 ==> arr[j] == 0
    // The final array is a permutation of the original one
    ensures multiset(arr[..]) == multiset(old(arr[..]))
    // Relative order of non-zero elements is preserved
    ensures forall n, m /* on old array */:: 0 <= n < m < arr.Length && old(arr[n]) != 0 && old(arr[m]) != 0 ==> 
            exists k, l /* on new array */:: 0 <= k < l < arr.Length && arr[k] == old(arr[n]) && arr[l] == old(arr[m])
    //ensures IsOrderPreserved(arr[..], old(arr[..]))
    // Number of zeros is preserved
{
    var i := 0;
    var j := 0;

    assert 0 <= i  <= arr.Length;
    assert forall k :: 0 <= k < arr.Length ==> arr[k] == old(arr[k]);
    //assert(forall n, m :: 0 <= n < m < arr.Length  ==> arr[n] == old(arr[n]) && arr[m] == old(arr[m]));
    while j < arr.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= j <= arr.Length
        // Elements to the right of j are unchanged
        invariant forall k :: j <= k < arr.Length ==> old(arr[k]) == arr[k]
        // Everything to the left of i is non-zero
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> arr[k] != 0
        // Everything between i and j, but excluding j, is zero
        invariant forall k :: i <= k < j ==> arr[k] == 0
        // If there there are zeros, they are to the right of i
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < j && arr[k] == 0 ==> k >= i
        // No new numbers are added, up to j
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < j && arr[k] != old(arr[k]) ==> exists l :: 0 <= l < j && arr[k] == old(arr[l])
        // The new array up to j is always a permutation of the original one
        invariant multiset(arr[..j]) == multiset(old(arr[..j]))
        // Relative order of non-zero elements is always preserved
        invariant forall n, m /* on old */:: 0 <= n < m < j && old(arr[n]) != 0 && old(arr[m]) != 0 ==> 
            exists k, l /* on new */:: 0 <= k < l < i && arr[k] == old(arr[n]) && arr[l] == old(arr[m])
    {

        if arr[j] != 0
        {
            if i != j
            {
                assert(arr[j] != 0);
                swap(arr, i, j);
                assert(forall k :: 0 <= k <= j ==> exists l :: 0 <= l <= j && arr[k] == old(arr[l]));
            }
            i := i + 1;
        }
        j := j + 1;
    }
    assert j == arr.Length;
}

method swap(arr: array<int>, i: int, j: int)
    requires arr.Length > 0
    requires 0 <= i < arr.Length && 0 <= j < arr.Length
    modifies arr
    ensures arr[i] == old(arr[j]) && arr[j] == old(arr[i])
    ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < arr.Length && k != i && k != j ==> arr[k] == old(arr[k])
{
        var tmp := arr[i];
        arr[i] := arr[j];
        arr[j] := tmp;
}
```

I run into the following problems:

- The 3rd postcondition `ensures multiset(arr[..]) == multiset(old(arr[..]))` fails on a return path, even though it holds as invariant of the loop, and the assertion at the very end `assert j == arr.Length;`also holds
- If I try to add additional assertions, the verifier times out. I tried the `assume false` technique, and I am able to identify which assertion is slow (always the one I add), but I don't know how to fix it
- If I remove any of the two assertions before the while loop, I run into timeouts
- If I comment the 3rd postcondition, I also run into timeout

What am I doing wrong? How should this proof be rewritten? Many thanks.

##UPDATE##

After following the tip to avoid nested existentials, here's what I think is what I want to prove:

```
function filter<T>(s: seq<T>, p: T -> bool) : seq<T>
  ensures forall x :: x !in s ==> x !in filter(s, p)
  ensures forall x :: x in s && p(x) ==> x in filter(s, p)
{
  if s == [] then []
  else if p(s[0]) then [s[0]] + filter(s[1..], p)
                  else filter(s[1..], p)
}

// Prove that adding one element to both seqs preserves the relative order of the elements
lemma SameSequence<T>(original: seq<T>, filtered: seq<T>,  i: T, p: T -> bool) 
    requires filtered == filter(original, p)
    requires p(i)
    ensures filtered + [i] == filter(original + [i], p)
{
// ???
}
```

I started writing this lemma, but it's becoming a monster, so maybe I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with one aspect of this: `ensures multiset(arr[..]) == multiset(old(arr[..]))`.

The changes I made were:

```dafny
method swap(arr: array<int>, i: int, j: int)
    ...
    ensures multiset(arr[..]) == multiset(old(arr[..]))
    ...
```

(add postcondition on swap)

```dafny
   // The new array up to j is always a permutation of the original one
   invariant multiset(arr[..]) == multiset(old(arr[..]))
```

(change loop invariant to remove `j` as not necessary)

With those changes that particular postcondition goes through.  To fix the ordering postcondition, I would avoid using nested existentials as you have.  Instead, my approach would be to define a recursive `function` (say e.g. `NoZeros`) which returns `arr` in the same order but with zeros removed.  My initial definition was:

```dafny
function NoZeros(arr: seq<int>) : (r:seq<int>)
ensures |r| <= |arr|
ensures multiset(arr) - multiset{0} == multiset(r) {
    if |arr| == 0 then arr
    else
        var head := arr[0];
        if head == 0 then
            NoZeros(arr[1..])            
        else
            [head] + NoZeros(arr[1..])            
}
```

But this does not verify yet.  We probably need a `lemma` of some kind to help here.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, something else is needed for proving that the relative order is the same.

Based on your hint about avoiding nested existentials, I started working on a different, simpler problem that is at the core of what I want to prove here. Basically, I'm looking for a proof that when you create a sequence from another sequence, applying a filter, and then you add the same element to both, the relative order of both sequences is preserved. I'm going to add this other code in a separate answer to my question.